# Export hierarchical grid to excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report which displays the data in hierarchical format. When I export it to excel I want the report to be exported in hierarchical format with having +/- signs.

Can anyone help me how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Its all in the groupings.

If your report has parent groups and some kind of visibility logic embedded, it will carry over to excel.

A quick and easy way to do this as a proof of concept is to do a report wizard and just give it an easy query that you can group.

The key though is to let the report do the grouping, not the underlying SQL itself.